# Need advice. How relearn what Ive forgotten?

Tags: self-learning, advice

The last time I studied mathematics and algebra was six years ago. I've since forgotten everything except quadratic equations, trigonometric functions and other things at the same level.
Now I want to relearn all this: combinatorics, linear algebra, probability theory. I'm looking at articles in wikipedia, and don't understand anything except the basics. Trying to understand a topic, I dig deeper and deeper into wikipedia and after a while, I can't even remember where I started.

So my question: what things I must learn for first steps?

Comment: write and draw (while reading)

Comment: hm..so simple advice, but I thinks that was realy good idea. Thanks)

Comment: Consider buying or borrowing a book from the library on the subject and read through it. Take time to do the exercises.

Comment: I somewhat edited your post. If you feel I've altered your meaning, please feel free to revert to the original. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks, my english not so good)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the basics, perhaps a free MOOC (massive open online course) and even Khan Academy might me a nice option to go:

https://www.coursera.org/category/math

http://www.khanacademy.org/

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia can be useful (sometimes very useful) for filling *gaps* in knowledge when you already have some background. But it is pretty useless as a place to *begin* (it often isn't even very good at giving pointers to good textbooks).

We live in a golden age for maths textbooks at different levels: there are a lot of quite wonderful books out there, written by experienced teachers, and often polished over a number of editions. Get yourself to a good library and see what is available that meets your needs and interests. Different books even at the same level will suit different readers, so find a book that looks as if it will work for you. Then borrow it, read it slowly and carefully, doing some of the exercises as you go along.